# Implementing differences of SURF between OpenCV and MATLAB

Tags: matlab, opencv, surf

Any ideas how MATLAB utilizes OpenCV function? I am implementing an image searching program both on MATLAB and OpenCV (on Android devices using OpenCV library, actually), but the image matching accuracy seems different (same algorithm, same dataset), 93% (MATLAB) to 83% (OpenCV). It seems that MATLAB calls ocvExtractSurf to detect SURF points, but why are the differences? Anyone help plz?